# Citations not showing up in text and bibiography in Overleaf

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, overleaf

I am adding my `references.bib` file to the root folder of the project beside my main `.tex` file. and i am importing it using the following code :

```
\begin{document}
 ...
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't show in the references section, nor the cite command are returning the numbers.
Why ?

UPDATE : one of the multiple alike errors that display is :

```
Runaway argument? ]{somerefid}\@safe@activesfalse  and \cite {somerefid\ETC. ! Paragraph ended before \org@@citex was complete. <to be read again> \par l.907 I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this control sequence to too much text. How can we recover? My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

Comment: you need to run bibex to generate the bibliography so pdflatex, bibtex pdflatex pdflatex normal sequence (oh except on Overleaf it should do that for you, so if it didn't,  show the error from the log or bibtex log)

Comment: check my question update for the errors

Comment: If you get _any_ error then (even though overleaf more or less hides them) you should not even look at the pdf, output it is not intended to be usable, just a possible debugging aid. Here the error is that you have more `{` than `}`  it's possible that you have literally forgotten a `}` somewhere or (more likely) you have used `\cite` somewhere where it needs `\protect` and have premature expansion somewhere.  Start by deleting all your cached files (overleaf has a menu option for that in its show logs area) and if the error comes back check where you have used a cite that is causing the error